# Where is the HAVE_UNISTD_H macro defined?

Tags: c, posix

```
#ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
#include<unistd.h>
#else
extern int getpid(void)
#endif /* HAVE_UNISTD_H */
```

I guess the idea is to check if header file `<unistd.h>` is available or not. if not then `extern int getpid(void)`
I know it's very basic.
But I didn't found good result via internet. What does HAVE_UNISTD_H macro mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means exactly that: `HAVE_UNISTD_H` is supposed to be defined if `unistd.h` is available. This is set for example by Autoconf; see [its header macro definitions](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf.git;a=blob;f=lib/autoconf/headers.m4;h=5fde7f5af8158e820bc78acb2b2569563547f6fb;hb=HEAD#l407).

This assumes that some external tool checks whether `unistd.h` *is* available and updates another header file (`config.h` with Autoconf, typically) to store that fact. The C compiler itself doesn’t set this.

Comment: ok. I got it. so how can I use gcc directly. currently `gcc misc16.c && ./a.out` will invoke `extern int getpid(void)` I want invoke `#include<unistd.h>` part

Comment: You need to use Autoconf or something similar, or if you want to do it manually, `gcc -DHAVE_UNISTD_H misc16.c`.